# Is there any way to get the server avatar of a member in discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been making a discord bot using the discord.py library. I want the bot to show a person's **Server Avatar**. Not the usual one but the one that is in beta testing I believe. Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score -1):

At the moment, it is impossible to do this. No documentation or update has been released yet discord.py. I think that it will be possible to do this using this method(maybe it works now, I haven't tried it):

```
user.display_avatar_url
```